# Calculating regrowth area

Tags: qgis, landsat, landsat-8

Using [Best Landsat-5 TM band combination for detecting fire scars](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108546/best-landsat-5-tm-band-combination-for-detecting-fire-scars/108569#108569) I am able to calculate burnt area in an absolute way (Normalized Burn Ratio).

Does a ratio or delta operation exist to calculate the regrowth area between two scenes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use NDVI to calculate regrowth between two scenes.

```
NDVI = ( NIR Band (B5) - Red Band (B4)) / ( NIR Band (B5) + Red Band (B4))

dNDVI =  NDVIpostfire - NDVIfire
```

NDVI assumes scene digital numbers (DN) have been converted to reflectance.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this ([here](http://wiki.landscapetoolbox.org/doku.php/remote_sensing_methods:normalized_burn_ratio)):

> "Typically, NBR and ΔNBR images are generated shortly after a fire burns to get an initial assessment of burn severity and to support field work. During the next growing season, NBR datasets are calculated again (called “extended assessments”) to assess vegetation survival and delayed mortality."

It is true that the ΔNBR Burn Severity Categories has two thresholds:

> High post-fire regrowth

and

> Low post-fire regrowth